# Calling a function in parent __init__ ,from a child class function

Tags: python, class, oop, vtk

I want to have something like this. If `OpenVTK(0)` calls, program starts and if it calls `OpenVTK(1)` it resets(but only some of features). (`elif vect[0]==1:` part of the code below does not have these properties)

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        
        self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OpenVTK(0))

    def OpenVTK(self, *vect, clik="", obs=""):

        global pr, aa, i, goster

        class MouseInteractor(vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera):
            def __init__(self, parent=None):

                global ee, dd  # aa

                self.AddObserver("LeftButtonPressEvent", self.leftButtonPressEvent)

            def leftButtonPressEvent(self, obj, event):
                if event == "LeftButtonPressEvent":

                    global bb

                    bb = self.AddObserver("MouseMoveEvent", self.leftButtonPressEvent)

                if event == "LeftButtonReleaseEvent":

                    self.RemoveObserver(bb)

                    def on_press(key):
                        print("{0} pressed".format(key))
                        if key == Key.esc:
                            MouseInteractor.dene(vec)

                    def released(key):
                        listener.stop()

                    # Collect events until released
                with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=released) as listener:
                    listener.join()

            def dene(*vecto):
                MainWindow.OpenVTK(self,1)
        if vect[0] == 0:

            i = -1

            etiket.clear()

            vec.clear()

            distp.clear()

            print("you'll see vect: " + str(vect[0]))
            print(vect)

            # print('Uncut Version')

            self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
            #print("self is : "+str(self))

            self.renWin = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow()
            
            self.renWin.AddRenderer(self.ren)

            self.iren = self.renWin.GetInteractor()

            self.iren.SetRenderWindow(self.renWin)
            

            reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()

            reader.SetFileName(filename[0])

            mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()

            mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

            actor = vtk.vtkActor()

            actor.SetMapper(mapper)
            

            style = MouseInteractor()

            style.SetDefaultRenderer(self.ren)

            self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)

            axesActor = vtk.vtkAxesActor()

            self.axes = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
            
            self.axes.SetOrientationMarker(axesActor)

            self.axes.SetInteractor(self.iren)

            self.axes.EnabledOn()

            self.axes.InteractiveOn()

            self.ren.AddActor(actor)

            self.ren.ResetCamera()

            self.ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()

            self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
            

            self.iren.Initialize()

            self.renWin.Render()
            

            self.iren.Start()
        elif(vect[0]==1):
            i = -1

            print("you'll see vect: " + str(vect))
            print(type(vect))

            i = -1

            etiket.clear()

            vec.clear()

            distp.clear()

            print("you'll see vect: " + str(vect[0]))
            print(vect)

            # print('Uncut Version')

            self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
            #print("self is : "+str(self))

            self.renWin = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow()
            
            self.renWin.AddRenderer(self.ren)

            self.iren = self.renWin.GetInteractor()

            self.iren.SetRenderWindow(self.renWin)
            
            reader = vtk.vtkSTLReader()

            reader.SetFileName(filename[0])

            mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()

            mapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

            actor = vtk.vtkActor()

            actor.SetMapper(mapper)
            

            style = MouseInteractor()

            style.SetDefaultRenderer(self.ren)

            self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)

            axesActor = vtk.vtkAxesActor()

            self.axes = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
            

            self.axes.SetOrientationMarker(axesActor)

            self.axes.SetInteractor(self.iren)

            self.axes.EnabledOn()

            self.axes.InteractiveOn()

            self.ren.AddActor(actor)

            self.ren.ResetCamera()

            self.ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()

            self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
            

            self.iren.Initialize()

            self.renWin.Render()
            
            self.iren.Start()
        else:

            del vect[0][0]

            # print('Cut Version')
```

But the problem is, although `self.pushButton2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.OpenVTK(0))` works and do the `if vect[0] == 0:` block properly, when I call `OpenVTK(1)` in `dene()` function it gives multiple errors like

```
2021-10-03 15:36:47.806 (1009.163s) [                ]vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWin:217    ERR| vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWindow (000002019A558A50): wglMakeCurrent failed in MakeCurrent(), error: The requested resource is in use.
```

I understand that error is because I cannot release the buffer source. But I copied the code of `if vect[0] == 0:` block to `elif vect[0]=1`.

Overall, I think, if I can call `OpenVTK()` from `__init__` of `MainWindow` it works well but I don't know how to do it.
NEW Edit: I deleted `dene()` function and instead try to call `OpenVTK()` from `on_press`. But in this edit I take this error:
`AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'vtkWidget'`. Although from above we can see that `MainWindow` does have attribute to `vtkWidget`.

```
def leftButtonPressEvent(self, obj, event):

    global data, vec, i, noktagoster, goster, x, y, mousehareket, clickPosold, selet, pointposOld, arb, distp

    if event == "LeftButtonPressEvent":

        global bb

        bb = self.AddObserver("MouseMoveEvent", self.leftButtonPressEvent)

    if event == "LeftButtonReleaseEvent":

        self.RemoveObserver(bb)

        def on_press(key):
            print("{0} pressed".format(key))
            if key == Key.esc:
                #MouseInteractor.dene(vec)
                MainWindow.OpenVTK(MainWindow(),0)

        def released(key):
            listener.stop()

        # Collect events until released
        with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=released) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. (Or if the indentation is correct, explain why everything is so heavily nested.)

Comment: This is an old code that one of the students back then written it. I don't know why this is in that way. But sure thing is that code works, so indentation is correct. Just help me pls, I don't have much time actually but I need to add an extension till tomorrow. And I think this is the main problem.

Comment: Why are you basing *your* work on questionable code written by some other student?

Comment: Well, I'm a sophomore and my instructor asked me help. So it's not my work, I'm only helping a little(trying actually)

Comment: Hi @soberdiony, I've posted an answer. Would you like to check it out?

Answer (score 0):

As the error (`AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'vtkWidget'`) is mentioning, The `vtkWidget` is not defined.
You are using this attribute which is not initialized first:

```py
# 1) "vect[0]==0": attribute vtkWidget is not defined
self.renWin = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow()

# 2) "vect[0]==1": attribute vtkWidget is not defined
self.renWin = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow()
```

Initialize the `self.vtkWidget` and then hopefully, the error will be resolved.